# How to fix kendo grid datetime format depends on local time

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have kendo grid with DateTime value and i live in time zone GMT +02:00 but my client database is in GMT +06:30 .

Problem is ,when i check in database time as 10:25 but when i check on my browser time as 05:55.

I'm using datetime format as below:

```
.ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(DateTran, 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss') #")
```

How can i fix this and directly show value in database? Is there any special format for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ViewModel with a setter and a getter that explicitly set the DateTime Kind to UTC.

```
private DateTime birthDate;
    public DateTime BirthDate
    {
        get { return this.birthDate; }
        set {
            this.birthDate = new DateTime(value.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        }
    }
```

Use the requestEnd event of the DataSource to intercept and replace the incoming Date field with the time difference.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoUIMVC5.Models.Person>().Name("persons")
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Events(ev=>ev.RequestEnd("onRequestEnd"))
        )
        // ...
    )

<script>
    var onRequestEnd = function(e) {
        if (e.response.Data && e.response.Data.length) {
            var data = e.response.Data;
            if (this.group().length && e.type == "read") {
                handleGroups(data);
            } else {
                loopRecords(data);
            }
        }
    }

    function handleGroups(groups) {
        for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
            var gr = groups[i];
            offsetDateFields(gr); // Handle the Key variable as well
            if (gr.HasSubgroups) {
                handleGroups(gr.Items)
            } else {
                loopRecords(gr.Items);
            }
        }
    }

    function loopRecords(persons) {
        for (var i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
            var person = persons[i];
            offsetDateFields(person);
        }
    }

    function offsetDateFields(obj) {
        for (var name in obj) {
            var prop = obj[name];
            if (typeof (prop) === "string" && prop.indexOf("/Date(") == 0) {
                obj[name] = prop.replace(/-?\d+/, function (n) {
                    var offsetMiliseconds = new Date(parseInt(n)).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
                    return parseInt(n) + offsetMiliseconds
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```